# How to make a php-google-adsense code be responsive on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, adsense

Is there any option to center google adsense code, so when I am using my mobile I can see the ads as responsive/compatible to mobile phones.

Currently using the code

```
<style="text-align:center;"><?php PopupContact();?></style>
```

Comment: in google adsense there is a new layout-version for responsive designs. have you checked that out already?

Comment: I allready tried it but unfortunately the Asynchronous mode isn't working